# TypeError: $data.quotation.company is undefined

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I have problem when I try to render data in my Vue3 application.

```
  data() {
    return {
      quotation: [],
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getQuotation()
  },

  methods: {
    async getQuotation() {
      this.$store.commit('setIsLoading', true)

      const quotationID = this.$route.params.id

      await axios
          .get(`/api/v1/quotations/${quotationID}/`)
          .then((response) => {
              this.quotation = response.data
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log(error)
          })

    },
  }
```

The weird part is when I try to access {{quotation.company}} in template I can see the element of "company" *without any error*. The error **TypeError: $data.quotation.company is undefined** occurs when I get in depth {{quotation.company.name}} for example.

Axios is getting data like:

```
{
    "id": 20,
    "company": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "xxxx",
        "slug": "xxx",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "xxxx",
                "slug": "xxxx"
            }
        ],
        "street2": "",
        "postcode": 11111,
    },
    "home_type": "xxxx",
    "Urgency": "",
    "description": "xxxx",
}
```

I really don't understand :/

Answer (score 0):

First the `quotation` property should be declared as an object like `quotation: {}`, then at the first rendering the field `company` is not available yet, so you need to add some conditional rendering as follows :

```html
<div v-if="quotation.company" >
    {{quotation.company.name}
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I don't get the "company is not available yet,". Isn't Await from Axios supposed to avoid this? and also the mounted() hook?

Comment: I don't understand your issue